# Mongoose when-query within or-query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type : String, required: true},
    location_a: {type: [Number], default: [0,0], index: '2dsphere'},
    location_b: {type: [Number], default: [0,0], index: '2dsphere'}
});
```

The input of my search has a location and distance. Now I want to get the Users that have either location_a OR location_b close to the searched location.

I've tried a query that looks like this:

```
query = query.and([
        { $or: [
            query.where('location_a').near({
                center: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]},
                maxDistance: distance * 1000, spherical: true
            }),
            query.where('location_b').near({
                center: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]},
                maxDistance: 100 * 1000, spherical: true
            })
        ]}
    ]);
```

But it makes my App crash with: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: your `and` isn't doing anything, and your `[ ]` brackets around your `$or` is in the incorrect places

Comment: Are you sure that the [ ] are the problem? Where should I place them instead?

Comment: please show me how you assign query before you do the above query

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong format in my query. This would be how you do it.

```
query = query.and([
        { $or: [
            {
                "at_student_location": {
                    "$near": [12.5386, 41.884],
                    "$maxDistance": 1000
                }
            }
            ,
            {
                "at_home_location": {
                    "$near": [12.5386, 41.884],
                    "$maxDistance": 1000
                }
            }
        ]}
    ]);
```

The problem is that a mongo only accepts one geoNear expression per query so it is impossible to do this.